# Is it possible to insert a shortcode into an image caption in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, shortcode, caption

Is there a way to insert a shortcode within an image caption in wordpress? Something simple like the below shortcode for instance, would be great to have inserted into an image [caption] tag if possible:

```
add_shortcode( 'current_year', 'sal_year' );
function sal_init(){
 function sal_year() {
 return getdate()['year'];
 }
}
add_action('init', 'sal_init');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to do this by just putting the short code in the html. Ex:

```
<img src=“/img1.png” alt=“[current_year]”/>
```

Comment: Your solution works but I am wondering if it's possible to insert a shortcode within the caption field of Wordpress's visual editor? it doesn't appear that it works properly...

Comment: Ah, sorry for the misunderstanding. No, I don’t believe this is possible.

Comment: No worries at all. I appreciate your help. This solution appears to do the trick: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113416/nested-shortcode-inside-caption-doesnt-process